# Reverse for 'create_chat' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create_chat/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I am building chat app and I am using Django Version 3.8.1. I am stuck on Error.

This view is for Chat with friend private.

views.py

```
def create_chat(request,id):
    from_user = get_object_or_404(User,id=id)
    user1 = request.user
    user2 = from_user

    chat_box = ChatBox(user_1=user1,user_2=user2)
    chat_box.save()
```

urls.py

```
path('create_chat/<int:id>/',views.create_chat,name='create_chat'),
```

profile.html

```
<a href="{% url 'create_chat' from_user.id  %}">Chat</a>
```

**The Problem**

When i open profile.html in browser this error is occured named :- `Reverse for 'create_chat' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create_chat/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']`

I will really appreciate your Help. Thank You In Advance.

Comment: unknown from_user.id, check this variable

Comment: @Ihar I am sorry, i didn't understand. Please upload as an Answer.

Comment: Can you show the  view which renders `profile.html` ?

Answer (score 1):

you must pass the variable from_user to the template, like this:

```
def create_chat(request,id):
    from_user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    user1 = request.user
    user2 = from_user

    chat_box = ChatBox(user_1=user1,user_2=user2)
    chat_box.save()
    context = {
              'from_user': from_user, 
              ...
              ...
              }
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

Comment: I have already create a template. I am putting a link to start a chat in User's profile. I don't need to render to some template. That's why i didn't create any template. By the way, I followed your Answer but i am getting the same Error.

Comment: But i really appreciate your Effort. Thanks. Can you give me another suggestion ? Please

Comment: check in your template what you have in the variable from_user.id, maybe there is an empty

Comment: It is just printing from_user.id

Comment: in template insert {{ from_user.id }} and look, what will be show

Comment: it shouldn't be nothing, there must be a value. you can make such link <a href="{% url 'create_chat' 2  %}">Chat</a> and see, will be error

Comment: Now it is saying :- `User matching query does not exist.`

Comment: def create_chat(request,id):
    from_user = User.objects.get(id=id)
should return a real-life record in your database. Check what you got  User.objects.get(id=id)

Comment: Can you please tell me How ?

Answer (score 1):

You should mention in the urls.py

```
app_name = "app_name"
```

and in the template

```
<a href="{% url 'app_name:create_chat' from_user.id  %}">Chat</a>
```

it should work

Comment: I got `Reverse for 'create_chat' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found.`

Comment: id is empty its mean id is not passing

Comment: for debugging it  i think a simple way is print the at into the command line, then see what it will print

Comment: Well, Thanks for your Help. I appreciate it.

Comment: All Right! Happy Coding :)